# FreeForm 4.0.10 - possible to have submit button download a file and submit form?

Tags: solspace-freeform, how-to

I need to set up a form where users submit information in order to download a file that should be downloaded as soon as they click the submit button (which is going to say "Download").

Is this possible? I know I can always have the form redirect to a page with the download link, but ideally clicking download would start the download and submit the form at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the form redirect page to allow PHP and set http headers to force download of the PDF. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386845/http-headers-for-file-downloads).

You can, of course, mix EE tags in that PHP-enabled template, so you could include a value in your segment variables to look up the right PDF to download, etc. Lots of options.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use jQuery to trigger a get request for the download URL?

Answer (score 1):

I think, it would be fairy easy by using the hook either freeform_module_insert_end or freeform_module_insert_begin. And in this hook you can use the force download of "download" helper.